# How to setup the "List-Unsubscribe" header in Amazon AWS SES API using the sendEmail function in PHP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, unsubscribe

I'm trying to setup the "List-Unsubscribe" header in Amazon AWS SES API using the sendEmail function in PHP. I've reviewed Amazon's documentation and many other posts here but haven't found anything that works yet. This is what I'm currently using:

```
$client->sendEmail(array(
   // all the main stuff like 'source', 'message', 'body', etc
  'List-Unsubscribe' => '<http://unsubscribe.link>',
));
```

... where http://unsubscribe.link is my unsubscribe URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use [sendRawEmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendRawEmail) instead of `sendEmail` in order to construct the raw message and add the `List-Unsubscribe` header to it.

**TIP**: It's better to use mailto-links instead of http-links as in `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@example.com>` since not all mail clients support http unsubscribe links.

Comment: thank you! so would it be as simple as this?

`$client->sendRawEmail(array(
   // all the main stuff like 'source', 'message', 'body', etc
  'List-Unsubscribe' => '<http://unsubscribe.link>',
));`

... or does sendRawEmail have it's own separate syntax to follow? - And thank you for the note on the mailto link, we will just need to build that system out.

Comment: @ben You can find more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684545/3770040).

Answer (score 0):

Since late 2019 there is "SES v2", so the the method name is `sendEmail`, but the advice is essentially the same. There is a `rawEmail` option within `sendEmail` that you need to use to be able to set your own headers.